# Determine where a UNIX alias is defined

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Is there a (somewhat) reliable way to get the 'origin' of a command, even if the command is an alias? For example, if I put this in my .bash_profile

```
alias lsa="ls -A"
```

and I wanted to know from the command-line where `lsa` is defined, is that possible? I know about the `which` command, but that doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: Did you try `type`?  It doesn't show where it was defined, but does show the definition.

Comment: @CarlNorum you should really just make that an answer.

Comment: @kojiro, it doesn't really answer the question, which is about *where* the definition is.  I thought it would be helpful information, though.

Comment: @CarlNorum `which` also works for aliases

Comment: The shell tracks the source file and line number where a function is defined, but not an alias. (You should be using functions rather than aliases anyhow, as they're considerably more flexible; for this particular alias, the equivalent function would be `lsa() { ls -A "$@"; }`).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As Carl pointed out in his comment, `type` is the correct way to find out how a name is defined.

```bash
mini:~ michael$ alias foo='echo bar'
mini:~ michael$ biz() { echo bar; }
mini:~ michael$ type foo
foo is aliased to `echo bar'
mini:~ michael$ type biz
biz is a function
biz () 
{ 
    echo bar
}
mini:~ michael$ type [[
[[ is a shell keyword
mini:~ michael$ type printf
printf is a shell builtin
mini:~ michael$ type $(type -P printf)
/usr/bin/printf is /usr/bin/printf
```

Answer (score 1):

While `type` and `which` will tell you the source, they don't look up in several steps. I wrote a small program for this: [origin](https://github.com/atorstling/origin). An example:

```
alext@smith:~/projects/origin$ ./origin ll
'll' is an alias for 'ls' in shell '/bin/bash': 'ls -alF'
'ls' is an alias for 'ls' in shell '/bin/bash': 'ls --color=auto'
'ls' found in PATH as '/bin/ls'
'/bin/ls' is an executable
alext@smith:~/projects/origin$
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will provide with information on what type of command it is:

```
ft () {
    t="$(type -t "$1")";
    if [ "$t" = "file" ]; then
        if which -s "$1"; then
            file "$(which "$1")"
        else
            return 1
        fi
    else
        echo $t
    fi
    return 0
}
```

It will either spit out `builtin`, `alias`, etc., a line like `/bin/ls: Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 executable` if a file, or nothing if not present. It will return an error in that last case.

Comment: Why would you ever use `which`? `type` can do path lookups too -- see the `-P` argument.